# How to change color and text inside VBA button?

Tags: vba, excel, button

I am trying to a button with VBA which change a color and all the writing inside whereby clicking on it.

How can I write the command for that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To change the color manually:

> 1. Right-click the button and choose Format Shape
> 2. On the Fill tab of the resulting dialog, set your color

Assuming that you want an RGB color from the color picker, the code might something like:

```
Sub ChangeButtonColor()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(228, 214, 186)
    End With
End Sub
```

Also, you can find more information on the Internet, for example [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/80738-change-command-button-color-based-on-cell-value).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I a, a beginner but when I create a button and link this macro, then I push the button but there is an error message from VBA.